# Reasons not to create an outlet by connecting directly between code and storyboard?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am following the fantastic Matt Neuburg iOS7 Programming Fundamentals book and have just gone through the section discussing various ways to create an outlet.

The very last one he explains is connecting directly between code and the storyboard (nib editor). All of the ones before that involve HUD popovers, engaging with the connections inspector directly and so on, and are generally more involved, having more steps to follow before an outlet is created.

I'm still not sure on why you would use one of these more involved ways to create an outlet? Is it safe to infer that they are more reliable in terms of knowing that the outlet is properly set up? And if so, how exactly do these other ways achieve this? 
The reason I'm asking is that I'd like to get on top of one way of creating outlets and if the hard way is the best way I'd rather get used to it right from the off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are pretty much equivalent, and it's a good idea to know about all of them, because a lot depends on where you are working and what you are seeing when you start. (For example, you can draw from the destination to the source or from the source to the destination.)

The problem with the one that makes your code for you (using an assistant pane so that you are seeing the storyboard and the code simultaneously) is:

- It takes a lot of space; it's not a very good approach on my small-screen 13-inch MacBook Pro, for example, because there really isn't room for that split pane arrangement.
- You have to get out of the split pane arrangement later, so why get into it in the first place?
- Most important: it works only in a limited range of situations. It works if what you're connecting to is the superview's view controller, but it doesn't work at all if you're connecting between one view and another.

So my advice remains, as implied by the book: be fluid in *all* ways of making / exploring outlets and actions! The more you know, the more comfortable and secure you'll be.

Comment: Thank you Matt. In that case, I'll experiment with them all as I start to make small programs and hopefully it will become more intuitive after a while. I have tracked you down on Google Plus. Hope it's okay to write you a line one of these days. And again, thank you for this truly wonderful book! Sinead

Comment: Delighted to hear from you, and thanks for the kind words about the book!